# How do I remedy "variable referenced before assignment"?

Tags: python

```
import random

class Tamagotchi:
    def __init__(self, name, animaltype, activities):
        self.name = name
        self.animaltype = animaltype
        self.activities = activities
        self.energy = 100

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getAnimalType(self):
        return self.animaltype

    def getEnergy(self):
        return self.energy

    def setHealth(self, newHealth):
        self.energy = newHealth

    def getExercise():
        activity = random.choice(activities)
        return (activity)

class Donkey (Tamagotchi):
    def __init__ (self, name, activities):
        super().__init__(name, "Donkey", activities)
        self.__home = "Beach"

    def getHome(self):
        return (self.__home)

    def __fightingSkill(self):
        print(self.name, "fights by kicking with their back leg straight into the opponents head")
   
    def DoExercise(self, activity):
        if activity == "fighting":
            energy = round(self.energy - 10)
            print(energy)
            print("Strong Kick")
        if activity == "racing":
            energy = round(self.energy - 15)
            print("Hard work")
        if activity == "Tail Launch":
            energy = round(self.energy - 1)
            print("I am a donkey, not a Walrus")

        self.setHealth(energy)
        if self.getEnergy() < 70:
            print(self.getName(), "Is out of energy")
        else:
            print(self.getName(), "Tired, New Energy:", self.getEnergy())

class Horse(Tamagotchi):
    def __init__(self, name, activities):
        super().__init__(name, "Horse", activities)

    def DoExercise(self, activity):
        if activity == "fighting":
            energy = round(self.energy - 15)
            print("Beaten")
        if activity == "racing":
            energy = round(self.energy - 5)
            print("I am a racing horse")
        if activity == "Tail Launch":
            energy = round(self.energy - 2)
            print("I am a horse i dont tail launch")
           
        self.setHealth(energy)
        if self.getEnergy() < 70:
            print(self.getName(), "Is out of energy")
        else:
            print(self.getName(), "Tired, New Energy:", self.getEnergy())



class Walrus(Tamagotchi):
    def __init__(self, name, activities):
        super().__init__(name, "Walrus", activities)

    def DoExercise(self, activity):
        if activity == "fighting":
            energy = round(self.energy - 34)
            print("Victorious")
        if activity == "racing":
            energy = round(self.energy - 5)
            print("I am a Walrus, i dont race")
        if activity == "Tail Launch":
            energy = round(self.energy - 12)
            print("Get launched lol")
           
        self.setHealth(energy)
        if self.getEnergy() < 70:
            print(self.getName(), "Is out of energy")
        else:
            print(self.getName(), "Tired, New Energy:", self.getEnergy())
   





Pet1 = Donkey("Gracy", "fighting")
print("Player1, you are", Pet1.getName(), "who is a", Pet1.getAnimalType())
Pet2 = Horse("Mabel", "racing")
print("Player2, you are", Pet2.getName(), "who is a", Pet2.getAnimalType())
Pet3 = Walrus("Steve", "Tail Lauch")
print("Player3, you are", Pet3.getName(), "who is a", Pet3.getAnimalType())
activities = []
activities.append(Pet1.activities)
activities.append(Pet2.activities)
activities.append(Pet3.activities)
print(activities)
activity = Tamagotchi.getExercise()
print("Activity chosen", activity)

#Accessing private attributes
Pet1.__home = "Land"
print(Pet1.name, "lives on a", Pet1.getHome())

#Accessing private methods
Pet1._Donkey__fightingSkill()

while Pet1.getEnergy()>70 and Pet2.getEnergy()>70 and Pet3.getEnergy() > 70:
    Pet1.DoExercise(activity)
    if Pet2.getEnergy() > 70:
        Pet2.DoExercise(activity)
    if Pet3.getEnergy() > 70:
        Pet3.DoExercise(activity)
if Pet1.getEnergy() >Pet2.getEnergy()and Pet3.getEnergy():
    print("Player 1 wins")
else:
    if Pet3.getEnergy() > Pet2.getEnergy():
        print("Player 3 wins")
    else:
        print("Player 2 wins")
```

This code doesn't seem to work, it talks about an error which is:
'local variable 'energy' referenced before assignment'.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mercinator. Could you first clean up your questions so that it follows [these guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That'll mean you should probably go back to your code and do some research on how to fix individual errors (e.g. `local variable "energy" referenced before assignment` you can search "python local variable referenced before assignment"). Once you've tried researching and solving your issue, if still unsolved, post your specific questions here with the short snippet of code that is causing the error and you'll find people able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error essentially means you are asking to use the value of "energy" even though it is empty(None/null)
In `def DoExercise(self, activity):` add an else statement that defines the value of energy when all `if` cases fail or give the value of energy before the `if` statement begins. It should solve the issue.

Comment: It's not empty, null, or none; it's *undefined*.